# Smarty wrap each character

Tags: php, smarty

Is it possible to wrap each character with smarty for example with a div?

This is a line im using to display the days from a timestam in php:

```
{floor($timeTill / 86400)|string_format:"%02d"}
```

it outputs something like:

50 or 37 or 10 or 07 or ......

Now I want each digit or character to be wrapped:

```
<div>3</div><div>7</div>
```

I need a non-javascript solution for this! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda dirty solution but should do the job

```
<div>{floor($timeTill / 86400)|spacify:"</div><div>"}</div>
```

Comment: Also I don't think it is the exact solution to OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the Smarty tag itself with `<div>`, i.e.

```
<div>{floor($timeTill / 86400)|string_format:"%02d"}</div>
```

**Edit:** Falling back to PHP

```
{php}
  global $timeTill;
  $timeTill = str_split($timeTill);
  echo '<div>'.implode('</div><div>', $timeTill).'</div>';
{/php}
```

Comment: it outputs <div>37</div> and not <div>3</div><div>7</div>.. what a wonder.. thanks but this is not the solution.